# Can I combine these 2 methods/functions into one?

Tags: c++, function

I have written the following code. One of these methods will check to see if the signal file can be accessed and the other will check to see if the background file can exist.

```
bool signalFileExist(string signalFile){
    ifstream f(signalFile.c_str());
    if(f.good()){
        f.close();
        return true;
    }
    f.close();
    return false;
}

bool backgroundFileExist (string backgroundFile){
    ifstream f(backgroundFile.c_str());
    if(f.good()){
        f.close();
        return true;
    }
    f.close();
    return false;
}
```

My question is: Can I combine these two methods into one?  Also, I will need to tell the user which of the files is bad if it cannot be checked. Is it possible to write the method in a way which will do that?

Comment: They already are exactly the same function. The only difference between them are the name of the function and the parameter names. It is down to the caller if they pass the name to the signal file or the background file.

Comment: Your linker may *already* be combining those two functions into one.  They produce the same sequence of instructions.

Comment: no, you can't. compiler will never know difference between strings 'backgroundFile' and 'signalFile' without your help.

Comment: Note that both can be condensed to `return ifstream(filename).good()`, and that the method you're using is unreliable, as some other process may remove the file between your query and your using the result.

Comment: how would file.fail() work? @Galik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They ... are the exact same method?

You can just remove either of them, and rename the other to something like:

```
bool fileExists(string fileName){
    ifstream f(fileName.c_str());
    if(f.good()){
        f.close();
        return true;
    }
    f.close();
    return false;
}
```

If you want to tell the user which file is bad in case of an error, you could do it inside the function, since you have the filename, or you could do it at the call site.

Comment: `f.close()` is completely unnecessary. This function can simply be written as `return ifstream(filename.c_str()).good();`  Also `fileName` should be passed by const ref, or even better pass directly a `const char *`